# INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

## Original Question

MySQL workbench allows one to define "inserts": rows to be inserted into the database on creation.  It does this by adding lines such as

```
START TRANSACTION;
USE `someDB`;
INSERT INTO `someDB`.`countries` (`name`) VALUES ('South Africa');

COMMIT;
```

However, if the database, table and entry exists, this throws an error.  Creation of tables does not, as workbench uses `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS` for those.  Is there a way to get workbench to insert using `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

### Half Solution

Running the script with the `force` argument:

```
mysql user=xx password=xx --force < script.sql
```

Ignores such errors, and is thus a solution in my particular case.  However, the actual question of modifying the type of `INSERTS` still stands (for interest)

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366436/continue-sql-query-even-on-errors)

Comment: Not sure I follow.  If this insert happens on database or table creation, how could there be pre-existing rows in any tables?

Comment: What are you trying to update?  The point is that you have a unique key on countries.  I expect you're not trying to create duplicates.  If it gives you an error, you can always choose to ignore said error (which is how this kind of thing typically works).

Comment: @MikeBrant It is possible that the table exists, and is populated, hence why the `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS` is important.  @john-green: Yes.  This suffices.

Comment: Would you mind giving us a little more context? Where are you creating the inserts?

Comment: @Snivs Not quite sure what you are asking, but the inserts are being created under the "inserts" tab of a table in an ER diagram?

Comment: Oh, if you re working on the ER diagram, maybe you could export the inserts into a separate sql script, so you could use INSERT IGNORE or INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE as you see fit.

Comment: It looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table might work for you.

Comment: Isn't there a window where you can type in arbitrary SQL?

Comment: I am not looking to use SQL that I write, I want it to come from the Inserts I set for each table in the ER diagram.  However, I understand if it is not possible.