# How to go to next statement in MySQL if current statement fails?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I run few `drop` and `alter` statements in MySQL workbench. How to skip to next statement when current statement fails ?

I am looking for a `GO` keyword equivalent of MSSQL server in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Use a semicolon (;). It will separate your statements.

Answer (score 0):

Which MySQL Workbench version you are using?

I am posting 2 options here:
In MySQL Workbench, just un-check the option under Query to "Stop Script Execution on Errors":

and in a newer versions use 'Toggle whether execution of SQL script should continue after failed statements'

For details you can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5366563/revisions)

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL Workbench, you can untick the option under Query to "Stop Script Execution on Errors":
Following link may help you.

[Continue SQL query even on errors in MySQL workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366436/continue-sql-query-even-on-errors-in-mysql-workbench)

Comment: The link is to another answer on SO, not to an external website. I think that is fine to keep.